# How to render <Label> and <Control.text> on different line in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-bootstrap, react-redux-form

I have a LocalForm inside a Modal. Here I have the code for the first 2 rows of the form.

```
<Row className='form-group'>
    <Label htmlFor='rating'>Rating</Label>
    <Control.select model='.rating' name='rating' id='rating'
                    className='form-control'>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </Control.select>
</Row>
<Row className='form-group'>
    **<Label htmlFor='yourname'>Your Name</Label>
    <Control.text model='.yourname' name='yourname' id='yourname'
                  classname='form-control' />**
</Row>
```

When the first row is rendered, it shows the label and the select input on different lines(select bar appears below the label). BUT the next row which contains the label and Control.text element does not render similarly. (The label and the text input appear on the same line.) How do I make it go to the next line as it happens with the first example ?

I have tried wrapping the Label and Control with div className='row' and also tried nesting a Row for it to appear on different lines. It does not work. The only thing which comes close to working is if I make the Label take up 12 colums by using md={12} but that messes up the alignment. Am I missing something ?